# Tomcat 7 Gets Errors During Startup of Java Project

Tags: maven, java-8, jersey, tomcat7, catalina

I have a Java project which was working perfectly before. Now I'm getting the errors below. The server startup is successful but the services do not work.
Java version of the project is 8 and I use Tomcat 7 server.

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ProjectName</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServiceNameRest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServiceNameRest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/projectName/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>...contextlistener.OCServletContextListener</listener-class>
   </listener>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ProjectName</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
  <finalName>ProjectName2</finalName> 
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.5.1</version>
         <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
            <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>            
        </dependency>   
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
            <artifactId>LibSVM</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
                    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asynchttpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>     
</project>
```

**Error Log:**

> Haz 27, 2020 2:16:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
> log SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
> jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:170)
> at
> jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:153)
> at
> jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:424)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
> at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)  at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
> at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Haz 27, 2020 2:16:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
> loadOnStartup SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web
> application [/DocumentClassifier] threw load() exception
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
> jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:170)
> at
> jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:153)
> at
> jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:424)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
> at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)  at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
> at
> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
> at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: @jan.supol I've changed the version of ASM but still getting the same error.

Comment: The exception says you have byte code of version > 1.8. How is that possible?

Comment: @jan.supol The exception is thrown in a class of jersey bundle but I don't really understand the reason

Comment: Jersey inspects resource classes using the ASM, so that it knows what methods to invoke upon http request. The ASM says that resource class has byte code of JDK > 1.8